# retrieving data from document file iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, plist

How do i get the file which is saved under

```
-(NSString *) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Answer.plist"];
}
```

---

```
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    { NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSLog(@"%@\n",array);
        NSLog(@"%@\n", filePath);
    }
```

and is there any way any way to add items to the plist without overwriting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Answer.plist"];

        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSLog(@"array, %@",array);
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:yourIndex];
```

or

```
[array addObjectAtIndex:yourIndex];

[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: It means you can enter any index at which you want to enter the string. e.g. 2 or 3 or 5..etc.

Comment: erm what if there is no index? as in i just want to add it in do i just use the addobject or writetofile

Comment: Then simple use [array addObject:YourObject]